# Generate a predicate out of two predicates (job for monoid, fold?)

Tags: functional-programming, fp-ts

I have two predicates

```js
interface Foo {}
interface Bar {}
declare const isFoo: (a:unknown):a is Foo
declare const isBar: (a:unknown):a is Bar
```

What is the functional way to combine two predicates to create a new predicate (for simplicity, let's assume it's `a => isFoo(a) && isBar(a)`?

With `fp-ts`, I initially thought I could `fold(monoidAll)([isFoo, isBar])`, but `fold` expects the array to be of booleans, not of functions that evaluate to boolean.

This works

```js
import { monoid as M, function as F, apply as A, identity as I, reader as R } from 'fp-ts'

interface Foo{}
interface Bar{}

declare const isFoo:(a:unknown) => a is Foo
declare const isBar:(a:unknown) => a is Bar

const isFooAndBar = F.pipe(A.sequenceT(R.reader)(isFoo, isBar), R.map(M.fold(M.monoidAll)))
```

But boy howdy is that convoluted. I thought there could be another way. I ended up writing my own monoid that takes two predicates and combines them, calling it `monoidPredicateAll`:

```js
const monoidPredicateAll:M.Monoid<Predicate<unknown>> = {
  empty: ()=>true,
  concat: (x,y) => _ => x(_) && y(_)
}
```

Is there a canonical FP way of combining two predicates? I know I could do something like

```js
xs.filter(x => isFoo(x) && isBar(x))
```

But it can get complicated with more predicates, and re-using a monoid makes it less likely I'll do a typo like `isFoo(x) || isBar(x) && isBaz(x)` when I meant all `&&` (and that's where a `xs.filter(fold(monoidPredicateAll)(isFoo,isBar,isBaz))` would help out.

I found a discussion about this on SO, but it was about Java and a built-in `Predicate` type, so didn't directly address my question.

Yes, I'm overthinking this :)

Comment: Yes, using a monoid instance is the best solution to your problem. And yes, your monoid instance for predicates is correct. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Contravariant.html#line-180

Comment: Just in case you don't know it here is an [article](https://medium.com/@drboolean/monoidal-contravariant-functors-are-actually-useful-1032211045c4) about contravariant functors which includes a section about a `Predicate` type where the author composes complex predicates out of simple ones. It involves monoids and contravariant functors, both of which are very useful for such a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```js
export const monoidPredicateAll:Monoid<Predicate<unknown>> = {
    empty: ()=>true,
    concat: (x,y) => _ => x(_) && y(_)
}
```

Then I could do

```js
import {monoid as M} from 'fp-ts'
declare const isFoo: Predicate<number>
declare const isBar: Predicate<number>

const isFooAndBar = M.fold(monoidPredicateAll)([isFoo,isBar])
```

Comment: Your example give a compile error `Type 'Predicate<number>' is not assignable to type 'Predicate<unknown>'.` Could you give an example / update your answer to make the monoid generic?

Comment: It does not give a compile error. I just pasted all this code into my IDE and it has no errors. I suspect you are not using it right.

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for a working solution, based on @user1713450's answer

```
import * as P from 'fp-ts/lib/Predicate';
import * as M from 'fp-ts/Monoid';

const createMonoidPredicateAll = <T>(): M.Monoid<P.Predicate<T>> => ({
  empty: () => true,
  concat: (x, y) => (_) => x(_) && y(_),
});

export const combine = <T>(predicates: P.Predicate<T>[]) =>
  M.concatAll(createMonoidPredicateAll<T>())(predicates);
```

Comment: Because you only use T in the return type, it's unnecessary. `unknown` works, and you've got something configured wrong on your end if it doesn't work for you. Generics are only useful if you're using them in multiple places to enforce them being of the same type. If you're only using a generic in a single place, you can replace it with `unknown`.